# mysql data when call in json, had \ format inside the data how to remove?

Tags: mysql

my data return is :

```
"durations": "[{\"day\": 365, \"duration_id\": 5, \"max_reward_percent\": 10.0, \"min_reward_percent\": 1.0}]"
```

I would like to turn them into

```
"durations": "[{"day": 365, "duration_id": 5, "max_reward_percent": 10.0, "min_reward_percent": 1.0}]"
```

how should I do?

Comment: The backslashes are needed because you have quotes inside a quoted string. They're not necessarily part of the data, just the way the string is printed.

Comment: The latter example is not valid JSON. I don't think you want that.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the backslashes `\`, you need to remove the quote-symbols `"` around the keys.
Your data return should look like this to avoid the backslashes:

```
"[{day: 365, duration_id: 5, max_reward_percent: 10.0, min_reward_percent: 1.0}]"
```

If in any case you absolutely need quote-symbols within quoted strings, you should use single-quote character `'` in the inner quoted string. E.g:

```
"[{'day': 365, 'duration_id': 5, 'max_reward_percent': 10.0, 'min_reward_percent': 1.0}]"
```